# Increase the time for console report in Gatling

Tags: java, scala, load-testing, gatling, stress-testing

I am running the gatling simulations and the gatling console report is printed every 5 seconds.

```
---- user-workflow ---------------------------------------------------------
[##########################################################################]100%
          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done:10    
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=1495   KO=0     )
> login-request                                            (OK=104    KO=0     )
> edit-request                                             (OK=255    KO=0     )
> update-request                                           (OK=257    KO=0     )
> delete-request                                           (OK=257    KO=0     )
> list-request                                             (OK=311    KO=0     )
> logout-request                                           (OK=311    KO=0     )
================================================================================
```

Is there a way to increase this time or better to print at the end of simulation?

I was looking at the [gatling.conf](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf) default configurations on the [github repo](https://github.com/gatling/gatling), but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible. See https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf#L109

In `gatling.conf`, set `data.console.writePeriod` to `0`.

Comment: The ticket you're mentioning is closed and flagged as released in milestone 3.0.0-RC1 so it has been released for a very long time (current version is 3.1.2).

Comment: My answer was deleted by moderators because I mostly provided a link to the configuration option: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf#L109. I'm done (again) with SOF. If you have any question regarding Gatling, I really advice you use our community mailing.